# Merge two DataFrames with the same schema

Tags: python, pandas

Assume you have two DataFrames

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([[123,321],[1543,432]], columns=['id','location'])
bar = pd.DataFrame([[123,421],[1543,436]], columns=['location','id'])
```

which you want to merge into one big table. However, as the schema (columns) are the same, in the resulting table a new column indicating the "type" should be added:

```
    id   location   type
0   123  321        foo
1   1543 432        foo
0   421  123        bar
1   436  1543       bar
```

Currently, what I do is

```
foo['type'] = ['foo'] * foo.shape[0]
bar['type'] = ['bar'] * bar.shape[0]
pd.concat([foo,bar])
```

Is there some smarter way to do it and in particular, avoid the first two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter `keys` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) - it create `MultiIndex`:

```
print (pd.concat([foo,bar], keys=('foo','bar')))
         id  location
foo 0   123       321
    1  1543       432
bar 0   421       123
    1   436      1543
```

And for `MultiIndex` to column use:

```
df = pd.concat([foo,bar], keys=('foo','bar'))
       .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
       .rename_axis('type')
       .reset_index()
print (df)
  type    id  location
0  foo   123       321
1  foo  1543       432
2  bar   421       123
3  bar   436      1543
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.concat([foo.assign(type='foo'),bar.assign(type='bar')])
print (df)
     id  location type
0   123       321  foo
1  1543       432  foo
0   421       123  bar
1   436      1543  bar
```

Comment: Why did you edit the solution? The first one worked as well, and was, IMHO, a little more readable.

Comment: sure, it is rollbacked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dror below is the timit results on the way you are doing the code and @jezrael 's method.

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame([[123,321],[1543,432]], columns=['id','location'])
bar = pd.DataFrame([[123,421],[1543,436]], columns=['location','id'])


def f(foo,bar):
    foo['type'] = ['foo'] * foo.shape[0]
    bar['type'] = ['bar'] * bar.shape[0]
    x = pd.concat([foo,bar])
    return x

%timeit xx = f(foo,bar)


>>>1.14 ms ± 5.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


def f2(foo,bar):
    pd.concat([foo,bar], keys=('foo','bar'))
    df = pd.concat([foo,bar], keys=('foo','bar')).reset_index(level=0).rename_axis(None).rename(columns={'level_0':'type'})
    return df
%timeit yy = f2(foo,bar)

>>>3.04 ms ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

it seems your code is faster.

Comment: WOW. That's an interesting point. And this is with mere 2 rows per table.Thanks for raising this.