# Can i specify db in MySQL query?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a `tableA` with the same structure in 4 different databases under the same host. Is there a better way, how to make a vertical join of these 4 tables than this in Python?

```py
import pandas as pd

import MySQLdb


dbs = ["db1", "db2", "db3", "db4"]

config = ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

for db in dbs:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
             user=config["db"]["user"],
             passwd=config["db"]["password"],
             host=config["db"]["host"],
             db=db,
             )

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query = """ 
                SELECT *
                FROM tableA            
            """

    cursor.execute(query)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    # todo and now join all df into one
```

in other words, can I specify `db1, db2, db3, db4` in the query?

Comment: use db.table like `select * from db1.tableA`

Answer (score 0):

If they are in 4 different databases I think that what you do here is good enough as long as the 4 tables are not so huge that it will make the process slow.

I would therefore recommend creating an empty dataframe before your for loop and at the end of the loop merge this dataframe with the new one you create. For this, a good way that would keep the information from which database the data comes from can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45914560/15174052),